# New line in text box in ZPL

Tags: zebra-printers, zpl

Note: I think I have tried everything mentioned here [New line in Zebra ZPL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13416299/new-line-in-zebra-zpl)

As input I get 1-3 paragraphs of text. The paragraphs are so long that I want automatic text wrapping, but I want to force a line break between the paragraphs. The below code is working otherwise but I cannot get the forced line break to work.

Here is my ZPL:

```
    ^FO30,473,0
    ^A0N,20,24
    ^TBN,500,500
    ^FDSome very long legal text that need to be printed in two languages[line break]Here is the same text in another language^FS
```

What should I replace [line break] with to force a line break?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I got it working by using ^FB instead of ^TB

```
^FO30,473,0
^A0N,20,24
^FB400,15,0,L
^FDSome very long legal text that need to be printed in two languages\&Here is the same text in another language^FS
```